# customize sharepoint search query

Tags: 2013, 2010

I have a sharepoint search query to get list of recently added pages based on managed meta data property of the page

```
CustomDate <= {Today}
```

This will fetch the pages which has `customDate` as today or before.

Is it possible to add 5 hours to the `{Today}` variable?

I have seen examples where we can add/reduce date using `{Today-1}`. How can I add hours like this?

Answer (score 1):

While you are preparing you query in the `Query Builder Pop up`. Place `{Today}` in the query text, and click on `Test Tab` on top (`Not the Test button`).

You will notice that the `Query Template Variable {Today}` contains only date, this indicates that deduction in Time from {Today} might not be possible.

Refer screen shot:

[image]

Comment: how can i specify time in that? or it is not possible to do so

Answer (score 1):

Basically `{Today}` is a KQL Syntax and you cannot play with hours/Time in KQL. You can only specify day values in KQL. See the [KQL Syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx) .

Comment: so in {Today} wont contain time releated info? basically its more like Date and not dateTime 
is it right?

Comment: Yes absolutely. If you want to manipulate with time , you will have to use FQL queries